# How to find tables in database with date range SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table wit customer with arrival date and departure date in a format '2014-25-11 00:00:00.000'. I am creating a query with to select those customer but I am having a error

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

But I want to find only with date `2014-25-11`

SQL query used

```
select FirstName, LastName 
from customer 
where ArrivalDate > '%2014-25-11 00:00:00.000%' 
  and DepartureDate < '%2014-29-11 00:00:00.000%'
```

Can anyone help me to write that query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Delete '%' from your values

Try this one:

```
select FirstName and LastName 
from customer 
where ArrivalDate > CAST('2014-25-11' AS DATE) 
  and DepartureDate < CAST('2014-29-11' AS DATE)
```

Comment: Appreciate that. But does this works as my data are stored in '2014-25-11 00:00:00.000' format but I only want to find between above arrival and departure date. Not with time

Comment: Tried but returns blank.

Answer (score 0):

if you only want to find the ones in the day 2014-25-11 you could use this

```
  select FirstName and LastName from customer
   where DATEPART(YEAR,ArrivalDate) = 2014 
and DATEPART(month,ArrivalDate) = 25 

and DATEPART(day,ArrivalDate)= 11
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want FirstName and LastName you need a comma rather than "and". Also remove the % wildcard. The below queries work in MS SQL Server.

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName 
FROM customer 
WHERE CAST(ArrivalDate AS DATE) = '11/25/2014';
```

If you would like values returned between two dates similar to what you have above, try:

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName 
FROM customer 
WHERE CAST(ArrivalDate AS DATE) BETWEEN '11/25/2014' AND '11/29/2014';
```

Comment: Tried with 1st option but didn't work -  returns blank.

Comment: What data types are your ArrivalDate and DepartureDate columns? You could try adding `CONVERT(DATE, CAST(datecreated as DATE), 101) = '11/25/2014'`

Comment: For both Arrival and departure, data type is datetime. Do you mean CONVERT(ArrivalDate, CAST(datecreated as DATE), 101) = '11/25/2014' ?

Comment: Sorry, I meant `CONVERT(DATE, CAST(ArrivalDate as DATE), 101) = '11/25/2014'`

Answer (score 0):

i'm afraid you have to order the date parts so that its ordered year-month-date.
this way the 26th Nov 2014 is between arrival and departure even if you compare the strings. The way your date-string is built, it does not sort that way. `2014-26-11` is just not between `2014-25-11` and `2014-29-11`.

```
select * 
from customer c
outer apply ( 
  select ArrivalDate   = substring(c.ArrivalDate,1,4)
                        +substring(c.ArrivalDate,9,2)
                        +substring(c.ArrivalDate,6,2)
       , DepartureDate = substring(c.DepartureDate,1,4)
                         +substring(c.DepartureDate,9,2)
                         +substring(c.DepartureDate,6,2)
) p
where '20141126' between p.ArrivalDate and p.DepartureDate
```

Comment: Thank you all of you. Sorry I was unable to reply you all back due net error. But I was able to use all of you and it worked. There was SQL error which was not executing properly. Thank you all once again.